# Why switching to single @Configuration class with explicit @Imports breaks @WebMvcTest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a quite simple app.
My project structure is:

```
.
├── App.java
├── context
├── controllers
├── dao
├── mappers
└── service
```

Initially **context** folder contained multiple `@Configuration` classes picked up automatically by `@ComponentScan` from `@SpringBootApplication`

[Current docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-configuration-classes) say:

> Spring Boot favors Java-based configuration. Although it is possible to use SpringApplication with XML sources, we generally recommend that your primary source be a single `@Configuration` class. Usually the class that defines the main method is a good candidate as the primary `@Configuration`
>
> ... You need not put all your `@Configuration` into a single class. The `@Import` annotation can be used to import additional configuration classes.

I decided to follow recommended way and removed `@Configuration` annotation from my config classes in **context** folder.

Now my App.java looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({CachingConfig.class, CustomDataSourceConfiguration.class, QueryDslConfiguration.class})
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Notice I did not use `@Configuration` on a class with `main` method, because there already is `@SpringBootApplication`.

Unfortunately after the change I faced a problem with my `@WebMvcTest` classes testing application **controllers**. Seems like now `@WebMvcTest` tries to load beans `@Import`ed by `@SpringBootApplication` (which is not expected by me). How is it supposed to use single `@Configuration` class then? I did `@Imports` from a class with `main` method as documentation advices (at least this is what I understood)

The first thing which comes to my mind to fix the problem and use recommended single `@Configuration` class is to create a separate `@Configuraton` class and put `@Import`s there.

And I also have an additional question. If I removed `@Configuration` annotation from **context** package classes and now `@Import` them, does it mean that @Bean methods are not proxied now. And it is not a good idea for one @Bean method to call another, right (because they are not proxied)?

Comment: Why did you do what you did? Keep it as it was before. That's how it's supposed to be. And if you need one of the Configuration-annotated classes in the test, import it in the test.

Comment: @JBNizet because after reading docs I decided it's a recommended way. I probably got it wrong